# set Dynamic Default Value for select dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a form, where I need to set the default value of the select dropdown in formik.

SelectDropDown.js

```
{props.options.map((option) => {
    return (
        <option key={option.id} value={option.id} title={option.title}>
            {option.name}
        </option>
    );
})}
```

[Code Sandbox LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-booth-u7inj)

App.js

```
<SelectDropdown
    control="select"
    name="episodeType"
    data-testid="episodeType"
    id="episodeType"
    label="Episode Type"
    options={dropDownValues} // how to pass defualt a props
/>
```

How to pass the default values as props so the page is loaded the values is selected.

Thank you.